# Change volume setting in ToneJS API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm new to the world of library API's, and not having much luck figuring out ToneJS. In particular I, am trying to change the setting on [volume](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r12/Volume#volume).

I've got: `let appVol = new Tone.Volume()`. I'd like the user to be able to change that default '0' setting. From looking at the link above, it seems like `appVol.volume = -12` should work to do this; it does not.

What is the correct code to do this? And if you can explain it - what am I missing here?

Comment: That SHOULD work, but without seeing how you're connecting the graph, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that `.volume`, like many properties in ToneJS, is a [signal-rate-property](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Signals) ... this means that it needs to be manipulated as such: `appVol.volume.value = -12`.

Signal-rate properties can be identified in the ToneJS API docs by the presence of a circled "~" to the left of the description.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected your volume to a master output? You probably want to change volume via Master, according to the [docs](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r12/Master).